# FedEx Address Validation module setup help

Tags: entities

I am trying to force accurate city, state and zip code entries when a user inputs their address. the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module by default doesn't require any accuracy. For example i can type "fake city" and it will accept that.

I found the [FedEx Address Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/fedex_address_validation) module, but as stated on the module page there is no user interface for connecting your FedEx credentials.

Does anyone know where to add my credentials?

> This module has no User Interface, so you must set the following variables:
>   fedex_address_validation_environment - must be either "test" or "live".

Live credentials are made up of the following 4 values:

- fedex_address_validation_live_key
- fedex_address_validation_live_password
- fedex_address_validation_live_account
- fedex_address_validation_live_meter

Test credentials are made up of the following 4 values:

- fedex_address_validation_live_key
- fedex_address_validation_live_password
- fedex_address_validation_live_account
- fedex_address_validation_live_meter

I tried adding to settings.php

```
$conf['fedex_address_validation_environment'] = 'test';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_key'] = 'LIVE KEY';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_password'] = 'FEDEX PASSWORD';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_account'] = 'ACCOUNT NUMBER';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_meter'] = 'METER NUMBER';
```

with no change. status still "Not configured for test"

Comment: I'm guessing here: use variable_set/get function, e.g: variable_set('fedex_address_validation_environment', 'test'); or put this variables directly to settings.php file. One of this way should work 100%

Comment: thanks for the input. I guess i dont understand enough about php to do this on my own.  would you be willing to write something out for me to get me started? like an example of how the first section would look?

Comment: You need to build your custom module. Here is total description for your needs: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/building-admin-interface-drupal-7-module-development

Answer (score 2):

Unless you desperately need those vars to be administered through the UI (in which case a small custom module would be the way to go), you can just add the variables through settings.php, using the following format:

```
$conf['fedex_address_validation_environment'] = 'test';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_key'] = 'foo';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_password'] = 'bar';
// etc...
```

Comment: I tried adding to settings.php

$conf['fedex_address_validation_environment'] = 'test';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_key'] = 'LIVE KEY';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_password'] = 'FEDEX PASSWORD';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_account'] = 'ACCOUNT NUMBER';
$conf['fedex_address_validation_live_meter'] = 'METER NUMBER';


with no change. status still "Not configured for test"

Comment: If you've done what the documentation says, and it doesn't work, report the bug in the issue queue (we purposely don't deal with bugs here so resolutions happen in the place most likely to get fixed into the actual codebase)